# Getting value of the input field in Angular 4 while typing

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an input field where a user can search different user in my app. But I want to make a search in such a way that when the user types in the input it should simultaneously search.
I have implemented my fuction which calls my back-end but i just want to know how can i send the value of input field with every keystroke.
Please help

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far so we can give you some pointers :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should handle the [ngModelChange](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel---two-way-binding-to-form-elements-with-ngmodel) Angular event (see **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-96yydk)**). It takes into account any kind of change in the input field (key strokes, cut/paste with context menu, etc.), and ignores key strokes that do not result in an actual change (e.g. pressing and releasing <kbd>Shift</kbd> by itself does not trigger `ngModelChange`).

```
<input [ngModel]="searchStr" (ngModelChange)="modelChange($event)" />
```

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
})
export class AppComponent {
  public searchStr: string = "";

  public modelChange(str: string): void {
    this.searchStr = str;
    // Add code for searching here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use **`(keyup)`** event on your input and pass the ngModel value to your service

```
<input   #term (keyup)="search(term.value)" type="text" class="form-control search-text-indent  searchbar-positioning" >
```

and in component.ts

```
search(term: string): void {
   //pass it to your service     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a form control to expose the `valueChanges` observable. This observable emits every time the value of the form control changes.

```
<input [formControl]="search">
```

This allows you to control the flow of the typeahead search

```
// component.ts
ngOnInit(){
    this.search.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            // debounce input for 400 milliseconds
            debounceTime(400),
            // only emit if emission is different from previous emission
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            // switch map api call. This will cause previous api call to be ignored if it is still running when new emission comes along
            switchMap(res => this.getSearchData(res))
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.result = res;
        })
}
```

With this, you are controlling how often the api call gets called (debounceTime & distinctUntilChanged) and ensuring the order of which the api calls finish (switchMap).  Here is a [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-control-typeahead?file=app/app.component.ts) demoing this.